# Making The Things Auto-Fit in Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using the listview for my events app.
But i encountered some problems.
The biggest one is, fitting the text.Maybe it is very basic one but i don't really know.
I want to make listview and the things in it (Image and Texts) auto-scale with the content.
Here is my screenshoot.

[image]

As you can see there is a few long text in listview and it overlaps the other text.
How do i correct this?

My layout is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/simge"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_foto" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Baslik"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
    android:text="Neşet Ertaş Konseri"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/simge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/kisaAciklama"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/simge"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Baslik"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Tarih"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Neşet Ertaş'ı Anmak Adına Böyle Bir Konser Düzenliyoruz.Tüm Fethiye Halkı Davetlidir."
    android:textAlignment="center"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Tarih"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="12/07/2017"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/simge"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    />
```

Comment: Post your xml layout please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should need to made 2 changes for a solution.

1- remove statement --> android:layout_above="@+id/Tarih" from TextView id-kisaAciklama,Becoz layout is being confused in two way relation dependency between views.

2- replace line android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/simge" with android:layout_below="@+id/kisaAciklama" in TextView id - Tarih

Comment: It worked well, thanks.I got a another question, if i change the text in kisaAciklama with code after the UI is created, UI doesnt update the sizes.How can i correct that ?

Comment: Hey @NickyRomero Please explain your uestion little more it will be  more good if you paste your code over here with explanation. Thanks